# montar icono en react native Material Top Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Tengo el siguiente código pero no genera ningún icono al cargarlo pero tampoco un error

```
    import { createAppContainer,createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Buscar from './Buscar';
import Menu from './Menu';
import Principal from './Principal';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'




const TabPrincipal=createMaterialTopTabNavigator({

    Principal:{
        screen:Principal,


    },  
    Menu:{
        screen:Menu,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintcolor }) => (
              <Icon name="reorder" size={24}  />
            )
          }
    },


},);

export default createAppContainer(TabPrincipal);
```

la opcion de menu es un createDrawerNavigator, lo que busco es cambiar el nombre menú por un icono pero, no se la manera es la correcta

Comment: Seguro que corriste el comando `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` e instalaste todo tal como la documentación indica?

Comment: si, corrí el comando npm install --save react-native-vector-icons como lo indica https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons pero aun así no me muestra ni icono ni un error

Comment: El comando que yo te indico que corras es distinto al que me dices que corriste

Comment: sí, intente el comando que usted me dijo, y pues no lo reconoce

Comment: Qué te sale cuando corres el comando?

Comment: no ya era con errores al escribir mal el comando.lo corregi  se me instalaron unos paquetes cerré el proyecto lo volvi a correr pero nuevamente no me muestra ningun icono

Answer (score 1):

En la documentación sobre 'createMaterialTopTabNavigator' puede leer lo siguiente:

> tabBarOptions - An object with the following properties:
>
> ...
>
> showIcon - Whether to show icon for tab, default is false.

Por tanto, añade tabBarOptions a la configuración de createMaterialTopTabNavigator y habilita la visualización de iconos. Quedaría algo tal que:

```
const TabPrincipal = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Principal: {
    screen: Principal,
  },
  Menu: {
    screen: Menu,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintcolor }) => (
        <Icon name="reorder" size={24} />
      )
    }
  },
}, {
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
    }
  });
```